# Получение IT-специальности

Tags: работа

Недавно передо мной стал вопрос - какое высшее образование получать и (что самое главное) получать ли его вообще. На данный момент вижу себя в будущем как разработчика ПО для мобильных платформ (aka iOS, Android и пр.), работающего в первую очередь на себя (как бы фрилансер).

Хотелось бы узнать, как те знания, которые вы получили в университете, помогают в освоении будущей професии и могу ли я их (знания эти, навыки) получить, например, на тех же специализированных курсах?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Знавал я парочку самоучек, которые получают (фриланс) неплохие деньги, но при этом совершенно не знают, ни алгоритмизацию, ни оптимизацию, ни булеву алгебру и т.д.
Много интересного узнавал лично у преподавателей, такого в интернете не найдешь (насчет курсов не знаю).

Некоторые вопросы вообще найти трудно. У меня было несколько преподавателей, которые имели доступ к зарубежной ограниченной литературе, имели свои разработки и патенты, а это все же весомый опыт.

Программировать никто почти не учил, давали основы, принципы, толково объясняли почему так, а не иначе и т.п.

Что касается мобильных технологий, пока вопрос памяти и производительности стоит остро. Поэтому человеку не знакомому с этой областью писать только "тормоза", имхо.
Но при этом, хочется заметить, что я не говорю, что наше образование - панацея от всех болезней. Много можно и нужно самому постигать, но фундаментальные основы, к сожалению, в гугле в слишком ограниченном количестве.

А хотите практики, никто не запрещает самому попутно заниматься фрилансом.

А еще учеба открывает области, которые могут стать для вас более интересными, чем телефоны.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Если не секрет, где учились?

Comment: Севастопольский Национальный Технический Университет

Comment: Фундаментальные основы есть там по много чему. Но вот только найти многие из них в достаточно подробном и понятном виде бывает затруднительно .з. Ну, когда они в виде djvu или картинок на паре каких-то левых заброшенных сайтов или в торренте среди тысячи других книг под каким-то названием, по которому и не понять, что там есть то, что именно ищется.

Comment: Фигня все это, есть уйма народу которая и с ВО и с опытом работы не может найти достойной работы и самореализоваться(говорю даже не об IT а вообще), главное чтобы вам это действительно нравилось, чтобы вы не ленились и чтобы у вас была цель...<br>
Вот у меня нет ВО, мне 19 лет при этом у меня уже есть 1 летний опыт работы ч\п и 1.5 лет + веб программистом, заметьте меня вообще ни в школе ни в ВУЗЕ ни тому ни другому не учили и ниче, кручусь както...<br>
PS:Прошу прощения за некропостинг :)

Answer (score 4):

Зачастую то, что дают в наших университетах, необходимо, но не достаточно. Всегда требуется собственное очень активное участие в своём дополнительном образовании. 
Обычно разработчикам требуется умение решать задачи, попросту be able to solve problems. Это уже не просто практика на языке N. Нужный язык программирования или конкретную технологию Вы всегда быстро освоите.

Answer (score 3):

Универ учит правильно и грамотно распределять свое время, девяносто процентов своего времени в универе , в большинстве случаев, ты будешь просто просиживать штаны, поэтому бери бук и сам на парах делай что-то. Конечно вуз дело делает, можно допустим попасть на препода, который скажет откровенно - ребята, это ГОСТ и мне надо его вам прочитать, но вы можете мне задавать по данной теме свои вопросы, мне попался такой препод, когда была возможность общались на другие темы, а не про старые забытые моменты нашего образования.
Отмазка универа мол вы все должны делать сами и не отмазка вовсе, действительно студент должен обучаться сам, вопрос в том, что, бывает момнет, студенту надо помогать, а тут и встает вопрос как в школе - дети учат учителя комп запускать. так что как посмотреть. однозначного ответа нет. что лучше один Бог знает. потому как для вас может и хорошо, для других плохо.
По мне, если вопрос именного очного обучения не стоит остро, идите на заочку и обучайтесь по сертифицированным учебным планам. Посещайте тренинги, там вы будете понимать от и до, если выбирете нормальные , за что все таки вы отдали ваши деньги и время, а в универе иногда и мысли посещают, а НАФИГА?? , хотя люди тоже определяюший фактор, может вы встретите единомышленников и замутите свое дело, кто знает)))))

Comment: Вот это стиль! Марсель Пруст нервно курит в сторонке.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, высшее образование техническое получить всё же стоит =)

Университет даёт, в первую очередь, не знания а очень важную вещь - умение учиться ПРАВИЛЬНО и самостоятельно, находить информацию в самых разных источниках. Правильно ставить вопросы и находить на них ответы. Или хотя бы путь решения.

Это очень много =)

Курсы же дают знания по конкретному предмету. И всё. Да, если надо быстро что-то освоить - это вполне хорошо. Там расскажут, какие где кнопочки нажимать, какие сложности и непонятности имеются и как их преодолевать. Там будут преподаватели, которые всегда могут что-то подсказать. Но там обычно в начале идёт куча всего того, что вы могли узнать в университете или самостоятельно. И курсы часто довольно размазаны во времени - полгода, год... В то же время, как самостоятельно это при интенсивных занятиях можно освоить за месяц. Или пару недель. Или ещё быстрее - но только то, что конкретно нужно (в курсах стараются дать всего понемножку и не факт, что хотя бы половина из этого нужна). В зависимости от обучаемости и имеющейся базы.

Возможно, по направлению "программист" (я не знаю - я на другом направлении обучаюсь) дадут порядочно знаний об алгоритмах, качественно **различных** языках и подходах к созданию архитектуры приложения и написанию кода. Хотя бы систематизировано расскажут - какие ж они бывают. =) А даже зная о наличии чего-то, это можно найти, научиться и использовать.

Если вы заинтересованы в высоком уровне своих знаний, качестве работы - высшее образование нужно.
Не обязательно ИТ, можно любое техническое, если уж не получится на него.

А куда вы примените свои знания и чему научитесь - зависит только от вас.=)

Comment: Я заканчиваю третий курс, и хочу сказать что мне университет ничего не дал. Насчёт умения поиска информации -- маны курить я научился сам. Полезен математический базис, алгоритмы -- но это лишь первые два года. Остальное -- гадкий шлак.

Answer (score 1):

Дело еще в том, что помимо непосредственно программирования, в университете учат с размахом. И, я думаю, знания математики не повредят ни одному программисту. Да и в общем мозги разшевелятся за 5 лет. Да и самовосприятие изменится, организованность. Было бы желание. Курсы - не то! Предполагают хорошую подготовку (если нужен результат а не корочка).

Answer (score 1):

Получайте классическое математическое образование.
Тогда без проблем освоите программирование на чем угодно под что угодно.
Это и собственный опыт (я диффурщик вообще-то), и опыт моих студентов.
Еще раз подчеркну, что классическое универское образование дает, в первую очередь, умение учиться и навыки самостоятельного получения знаний - а это бесценно!

Успехов!

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю как в столицах а в области программировать почти не учат. (Что-то дают, но чертовски мало для настоящей работы). И я подозреваю так везде.

С другой стороны, возможно пригодится сам диплом. Тут я ничего не скажу, ибо сам пока не доучился.

Comment: Вот да, общался немного со студентами - почти никакой практики + теория та что в любой книжке по языку N.

Comment: На самом деле всё очень грутно. У нас был предмет "Языки программирования" и мы там проходили старющий фортран. Весь семестр.

Comment: Я учусь на теплофизика и у нас были из языков программирования фортран, РНР, Matlab, Scilab, FreeFem, ну и эпизодически - пишите на каких хотите. Для программиста это, конечно, ни о чём, но всё же =) Да и благо, программировать я научился раньше сам .-. А кто не умел программировать - тот и не научился. Впрочем, им было и не интересно.

Comment: Фортран стареющим называть рановато, он всё-таки развивается (если это не fortran-IV или fortran-77). Для физиков неплох и питон ("лучший друг физика").